# How do I simulate the edge glowing animation like in Android OS when dragging from the edge in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uigesturerecognizer

So the situation is that I have a UIScrollView with a UITextField and UITextView embedded in it. I have the UITextField on top and the UITextView set up as a the frame as the height of the contentSize. I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer setup to detect a swipe from the right edge within a certain starting point and once you drag it a far enough distance it activates an action.

I want the edge to glow like the below image. From the right edge to grow in intensity the closer I get to that preset distance. I'm not so great at drawing and animation yet so I was thinking a CALayer? I just havent been able to form the proper way of doing this. I've also been reading all the documentation again but still having [code]writers block.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a blue view with an opacity low to make it semi-transparent and apply a mask to this view to see only the ellipse.

You are looking at something along those lines:

```
UIView* yourView = [[UIView alloc] init];
yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
yourView.opacity = .3; // for e.g put you can set different opacity value of course
[yourView layer].mask = maskEllipse; // where maskEllipse is a white view with an ellipse shape
```

There seems to be an opaque blue view that fades on the side on top of this first view. You could have the same approach for this second view but the mask would need to be applied only on the sides.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to implement code similar to this. As soon as I have it finished I'll update this post with the code for posterity.